Rotate Image getting cropped in Compose Image
I am trying rotate a Image View in compose but noticed that image is being cropped from top and bottom when rotated by 90 / in Horizontally.
here is my code :
   Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                 .aspectRatio(9f/16f ,matchHeightConstraintsFirst = true),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            
        ) {
        Image(
                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                    model = scannedPage.rawImagePath
                ),
                contentDescription = "Slider Image",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier =
                Modifier
                    .rotate(scannedPage.imageRotate),
            )
       }

Preview :
Image Rotated by 90:

No Rotation Image :

Why is this happening?
Is there any other approach to rotate a image correct while maintaining the aspect ratio of image too.

First of all you are not changing aspect ratio of parent container while Image is returned. Probably assigning rotate on Box and before aspectRatio will fix the issue

@Thracian Not working ,i am getting the same cropped image when rotate by 90.
Can u send the sample code ,how to rotate a Image with boxfit as fit.
